# Use Case Diagram with Multiple Systems?

Tags: uml

[image]

I don't know how to make the following use case diagram with multiple systems.
What happens if I use for that example: 
[image: enter link description here]

Another system that is for the developer actor that add the items.
This is something what I am searching for:

[image: Image not found]
<sub>(source: [gliffy.com](https://www.gliffy.com/_media/diagram_cache/5006088_M.png))</sub>

but is it possible to use multiple systems and connect them?

---

#### I have edited my idea here:

I have to sides, the Client side and server side, where admin can edit data, in administration menu, so it updates the server database and and the database of the client... but i don't now the right notation to use...

Comment: The 2nd example is perfect. You can add as many system boundaries as needed. Where is the problem? The connection of the systems themselves?

Comment: I have two two systems, a server and a client. the server is for admin and client for user - but the client does have uses cases, thats depend on action of admin on server side... i dont know how it works

Comment: I attached an image with my idea to do it, but I dont know if the notation is right, whether to use << include >> or not :S

Answer (score 2):

Crossing borders with use cases is ok in principle. In your example the Update Database should have an `<<extends>>` from Edit Data (needs to point from the second to the first!).

Note that you should avoid the use of those extension. If your use case diagrams resemble a spider's web your design is broken. Remember that it's called use case synthesis - not analysis. The first will try to gather things under a hat while the 2nd is used in coding to break down complexity.